# How can I discard a commit on a branch I don't have push rights to?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally committed some changes to my local checkout of Master branch in Sourcetree, which is a protected branch. I cannot push my commit and when I try to discard it, this only creates a second commit to undo the first - now I have two commits I cannot push!

How can I simply discard/rollback this commit so my local branch is in sync with the remote one again? Ideally using Sourcetree itself.

Comment: I don't want to reset the whole repo @joe just one branch

Comment: The instructions in that answer are for a single branch. (`master` in that case, but the steps are general.)

Comment: my apologies @joe - seems an exact dupe. Thanks for the link